# Problems in orientation changing (Linux)

Tags: android, android-orientation

I'm trying to change orientation of my android emulator. 
I have tried to use different combinations: Ctrl+ F11, Ctrl + F12, Ctrl + fn + F11, etc. but the orientation stays the same. In Windows everything works correctly, but nothing works in Ubuntu.
Help me to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-F11 and Ctrl-F12 work in Ubuntu on a PC environment. Whether or not a Fn key is involved depends upon your keyboard (e.g., notebooks might need Fn, desktop/external keyboards usually do not have Fn).